# Spring Boot does not run Unit Tests whenever App is starting

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm starting to write Unit Testing to a Spring Boot app on Intellij Idea.

I have this test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort=true)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)

public class UserTest {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void login()  {
        User myUser = new User();
        myUser.setUsername("myName");
        myUser.setPassword("myPass");

        ResponseEntity<String> r = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:"+port+"/users/login?username="+myUser.getUsername()+"&password="+myUser.getPassword(), String.class);
        assertThat(r.getBody(), containsString("myName"));
    }

    @Test
    public void getUsername() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        assertNotEquals("myName", user.getUsername());
    }
```

}

This works fine when i run it through Run->Run 'UserTest', but how do i get in to run automatically when I start the application, and get it to output the test results on Spring Boot output window?

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA, open the Run/Debug Configurations menu and create a new configuration based off the Maven default configuration.

Put the following in the Command Line field: `clean test spring-boot:run`

Then run your application using this new configuration.

[image]

Comment: And if I'm using Gradle?

Comment: Create a new configuration based off the Gradle default configuration.  Then put the Gradle tasks you want executed in the form fields.